# HP Paviliion g6 with WiFi button always disabled

Tags: wireless

I have an HP Pavilion g6 2307-sp, with Ubuntu 13.10, and I've got the "F12 can not enable wireless networks" problem.

I've been looking around here, but so far, nothing has worked for me, yet.

Can anyone give me a help?

Thanks in advance.
Luis

Comment: `http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03593041.pdf` shows no hardware switch for wireless, so I would try booting from a different distro on a LiveUSB to see if the problem is distro-related.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Is your wireless now unblocked? If so, let's make the change permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist hp-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```